# HTMLAgilityPack selecting Multiple nodes with different Xpath ID C#

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm using HTMLAgilityPack to pull the Digital Media table from Amazon, this is for my work. The xpath shows they all have different IDs example:

```
    //*[@id="result_0"]/td[2]/div/a
   //*[@id="result_1"]/td[2]/div/a
   //*[@id="result_2"]/td[2]/div/a
```

And so I cannot just use selectNodes as I would like, unless there is away around this?
Currently i'm doing it like this, but it doesn't seem right?

```
        var doc = web.Load("https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Ddigital-music&field-keywords="+txtInput.Text+"&page="+nowNum+"");

     for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
         try
             {
                node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"result_"+i+"\"]/td[2]/div/a").InnerText;
             }
        catch (exception)
        {
        throw;
        }
    }
```

Is there anything wrong with the way I have done it? Or is there a way i can use selectNodes instead of having to select each one individually using these Xpaths with different IDs?

Thank you
Ant

Comment: Can you post a sample of the HTML you are trying to parse?

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [start-with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with), this way you can use `SelectNodes`:

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[start-with(@id, 'result_')]/td[2]/div/a");
```

This way you get all the `result_X` nodes, I believe this is better because your for loop assumes that there are 50 results.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. This seems like the sort of thing I was looking for although now this is giving me other errors.
"System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: 'Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.'"

Comment: Ahh i got it working thank you

"var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[starts-with(@id, 'result_')]/td[2]/div/a");"